# update manager is not working

Tags: updates

Something happened, and I'm no longer able to access my update manager.  I'm getting the red ball with white minus sign at the top of my desktop, and when I click on it, it tells me that my daemon has crashed.  I'm using 12.04.  Restarting does nothing.  What can I do?

Comment: Try re-installing the update Manager using this command 

sudo apt-get install --reinstall update-manager-core update-manager

Answer (score 0):

You could try this, maybe your system's dependencies are broken by any means. You can fix it by just typing the following commands in terminal. By Pressing Ctrl + Alt + T, which opens your Terminal.

```
sudo apt-get install -f
sudo apt-get update
```

You may also try this:

[12.04 update-manager problem](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1981033)